# Apache Airflow webUI tree view is too slow

Tags: airflow

I'm using apache airflow(v1.8.1) for workflow management. After 4-month use, the tree view page become too slow when I want to jump into a dag. The loading time for this page takes minutes.

It looks like the tree view page is slow only for dags with a big complex tree. From chrome devtools, I can see the page is too huge(295M):

[image]

do you have any ideas?

Comment: I found this too - one hacky way i got around it was editing the airflow source code to have the drop down default to 5 runs instead of 25. Ideally this would be a param or something. here is my thread to the dev's https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@airflow.incubator.apache.org/msg03237.html

Comment: thanks reply, I also changed the default page to graph view. this avoid to visit that page.

Comment: set the default view in `class airflow.models.DAG`: `default_view (string) – Specify DAG default view (tree, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times)`

Answer (score 2):

Following up on my comment.

One sort of hacky way to get around this is to change the default from 25 to 5 in the source code in this file:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/d99053106e58ec377333c64f68ee84ed1dcdf61c/airflow/www/forms.py

This is not great though.

Probably worth filing a feature request [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW/issues) to make some of the UI defaults like this configurable.

However i know v2.0 has some UI changes that might negate this issue, not sure.